# Excel VBA Referencing to InkPicture on worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, reference, microsoft-ink

I have completed a few fairly simple Excel & VBA projects but I am quite new to OLEObjects (noob!).
After some research I have managed to place InkPicture on Excel worksheet ("Sheet1") using VBA (code below)

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="msinkaut.InkPicture.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=ActiveCell.Left, Top:=ActiveCell.Top, Width:=240, Height:=70).Select
```

Does anyone know how to access the (embedded) InkPicture properties and methods using VBA?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim yourObject As OLEObject
Set yourObject = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="msinkaut.InkPicture.1", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=ActiveCell.Left, Top:=ActiveCell.Top, Width:=240, Height:=70)
```

Comment: Many thanks! I can now reference it. Moreover, it behaves exactly as it should. Without declaring it as OLEObject it appeared on the sheet but had to be deselected to paint a stroke (it also only accepted single stroke).